# Retrieving specific fields from JSON file in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to retrieve specific fields from a [JSON file](http://api.wunderground.com/api/a21d4c37b507ea76/conditions/forecast/q/19104.json) that is being retrieved from Wunderground.com.

I tried to post the relevant information in this, but couldn't get it formatted correctly. I am trying to retrieve the longitude and latitude, under the "current_observation" section. I am using Gson 2.2.4. This is the code I currently have:

```
    String key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    String sURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + key + "/conditions/forecast/q/19104.json";

    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    URLConnection request = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
    request.connect();

    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
    JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); 
    JsonElement latitude = rootobj.get("current_observation");

    System.out.println(latitude);
```

This currently gets everything under the "current_observation" tag, and prints it to the screen. I can not figure out how to access anything under that. I saw several posts on here about using a JsonArray, but no matter what I tried, I could not get it to work correctly. So how do I retrieve a specific field from a JSON file? Thank you for any guidance you can give me, and please let me know if I should provide any additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JsonElement` is a common interface which is subclassed by two important other classes which are `JsonArray` or [`JsonObject`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html).

Since you are not providing Gson a type to reflect the information from (and fill a corresponding object) you must go by hand. Since `"current_observation"` is a dictionary type then it's a `JsonObject` and you can do:

```
 JsonObject observation = root.getAsJsonObject().get("current_observation").getAsJsonObject();
```

At this point you can retrieve specific fields like you were doing previously:

```
float longitude = observation.get("longitude").getAsFloat();
```

and so on.

For specific field you may want to provide custom deserializer or serializer. Actually the best solution would be to have your mirrored structure in code repository, eg:

```
class Observation
{
  float latitude;
  float longitude;
  // other fields you are interested in
}
```

so that you can provide your own [deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) and do:

```
Observation observation = gson.fromJson(root.getAsJsonObject().get("current_observation"), Observation.class)
```

and let Gson do the dirty work.

Comment: In this case you actually need to retrieve another `JsonObject`, because `latitude` is in `current_observation` > `display_location` > `latitude`. Or `current_observation` > `observation_location` > `latitude`, because there are actually two `latitude` in that JSON file, I don't know which one he wants.

Comment: @ArianJM: Yes the structure is irrelevant in any case, I would like to make him understand the basic principle behind this. Which is traversing the tree through `getAsJsonObject` and `getAsJsonArray`. But having a custom type adapter is still the preferable solution IMHO

Comment: Thank you so much! Using your example, I was able to get the latitude and longtitude like I needed, after creating another JsonObject like @ArianJM said, for the display_location. This was an excellent description, and really helped me understand how Json is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Now as your `current_observation` JSON itself contains some `JSON` as well as `String` fileds. I will tell you for 1 string feild `station_id` and other `JSON` field `image`.You can use like this :-

```
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
            JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
            JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); 
            JSONObject curObs = (JSONObject)rootobj.get("current_observation");
            JSONObject image = (JSONObject)curObs.get("image"); // image is a JSON
            String imageUrl= (String)image.get("url"); // get image url
            String stationId = (String)curObs.get("station_id"); // get StationId
```

Similarly you can do for other attributes of `JSON` also. Hope this helped.